# python if else comprehension with two lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have this code:

```
a = []
b = []
for row in range(10):
    if x[row] is True:
        a += list_features[row]
    else:
        b += list_features[row]
```

Where `list_features[row]` is a 1D list. I would like to do this in list comprehension I know something like the below code would work:

```
a+= [list_features[row] for row in (10) if x[row] is True]
b+= [list_features[row] for row in (10) if x[row] is False]
```

How would one do this with just one comprehension in one line?

Comment: Why do you need list comprehension here?

Comment: What is `x` here?

Comment: x is a boolean value taken from another list of boolean values. It doesn't matter really, code is pretty simple I just wanted to know if its possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

since you have 2 targets, list comprehension isn't adapted (and using 2 comprehensions means testing `x[row]` twice, once to build `a` and once to build `b`)

Something that would be slightly more concise would be a ternary expression to choose the target (you cannot use `+=` directly on an expression but you can use `extend` which does the same thing):

```
(a if x[row] else b).extend(list_features[row])
```

that said, I would not use `row` to index both lists (cumbersome, unpythonic and underperformant when doing sequential access), but `zip`:

```
for i,lf in zip(x,list_features):
   (a if i else b).extend(lf)
```

the only "risk" is that one of the lists is shorter than the other, in which case, you don't get any error, and the result is incorrect (a proper fillvalue given to `itertools.zip_longest` can be an alternative in that case)

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is to do it in one line:

`a, b = [list_features[row] for row in range(10) if x[row]], [list_features[row] for row in range(10) if not x[row]]`

This doesn't assume that `x` or `list_features` are sequences, they could be dicts.

But there's really no point in putting everything in one line. Writing clear code is more important.

Comment: you can lose the outer `[]` as without it it creates a `tuple` which unpacks very well into `a,b`. +1 for "they could be dicts" which justifies the usage of the subscript notation instead of `zip`

Answer (score 0):

Your list comprehensions are almost fine, so you don´t need the first 2 lines, but only list comprehensions, so instead of:

```
a = []
b = []
for row in range(10):
    if x[row] is True:
        a += list_features[row]
    else:
        b += list_features[row]
```

use

```
a = [list_features[row] for row in range(10) if x[row] is True]
b = [list_features[row] for row in range(10) if x[row] is False]
```

Note the `range()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`zip()`](https://kite.com/python/docs/builtins.zip) and get rid of `row` counter, since you don't need it

```
a = [feature for feature, enabled in zip(list_features, x) if enabled]
b = [feature for feature, enabled in zip(list_features, x) if not enabled]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use list comprehension, you're constructing a list by following a pattern, you're not adding an element to an existing list. Which also means you don't have to declare it first.

The correct syntax is  `a = [[list_features[row] for row in range(10) if x[row] is True]]`

Also you don't have to write `if x[row] is true` explicitly, since I suppose x is an array of boolean.

`a = [[list_features[row] for row in range(10) if x[row]]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
_ = [a += list_features[row] if x[row] is True else b += list_features[row] for row in range(10)]
```